# scroll box with button for terms and condition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to put scroll box with a button for Terms and condition. The button will be enabled only after the user scrolls down the scroll box to ensure that the user has completly read the terms and conditions.

Comment: Was there a question in there?

Comment: Yeah. " _Can you develop it for me?_ " (or so it seems)

Comment: read some tutorial and try it before asking. SO is not a labour for making your homework..

Answer (score 5):

So put the button at the end of the Terms and Conditions.

Comment: I laughed, and upvoted, but I think he wants a grayed out button to become not grayed out once the T+Cs box has been scrolled to the bottom. :3

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by handling the scroll events through javascript

Answer (score 1):

Have a floating div at the bottom of the terms page. Have a mouse over event which will enable the accept button. Not exactly sure if you have a doubt..